# Reduce initial connection and ssl time on my server

Tags: apache, ssl, drupal-9

I'm using Apache server with Centos7. Dedicated 16 GB RAM. Drupal 9 website. I would like to reduce initial connection and ssl time response on my server.
Initial connection is about 400 ms and ssl time is about 200 ms. Is there any advice how to reduce those values? Where is the problem? What to check?
[Waterfall statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf2M2.png)

If I switch only to http protocol,Initial connection is about 20 ms.